# How do I hide the plugin list from my users?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I want to hide my plugin list from my users. How do I do that? They just type `/plugins` and all plugins are shown. Is there any option to disable this? I am using Essentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [PluginList](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/pluginlist/).

Answer (score 4):

To completely hide your plugin list from other users you need to do the following:

1. Override the /plugin command.
2. Override the /pl command.
3. Override the /version command.
4. Override the /ver command.
5. Override the /help command.
6. Override the /? command.
7. Override all plugin commands with the string response "Unknown command. Type \"help\" for help." or some response that is equivalent to what an invalid command would also be for all default users.

---

**Solutions**

- *Solve problems 1, 2*:

Bukkit **PluginList** plugin should solve 1 and 2 if working correctly, but the users can easily find out your plugins still by using the /? command.

- *Reduce the effects of problems 1, 2, 3, 4*:

Bukkit **Vanilla** plugin should at least block the commands associated with 1, 2, 3 and 4. However, if they are blocked, a user will notice that the command response is missing. They still can figure out all your plugins using the /? command.

- *Solving problem 5*:

Since you already have **Essentials**, you can override the /help command by placing a help.txt file into the 'Essentials' folder. You need to format the text properly to make it unsuspicious. This only solves the problem with the /help command revealing information.

- *Solving problems 1 through 6*:

Since you already have **Bukkit**, the server which **Essentials** is made for, then you can override commands using the [aliases](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Bukkit.yml#aliases) in the '**Bukkit.yml**' file. You can override the commands here. For example, if you type the following:

```
aliases: 
  ?: help
  plugin: help
  pl: help
  version: help
  ver: help
```

Make sure that you indent the aliases two spaces, then you will successfully have overwritten all those commands with the command **help**. You may forward these to other commands such as **motd**, **rules**, **info** and alter what they print out by editing 'motd.txt', 'rules.txt', and 'info.txt' in the 'Essentials' folder. However, you may want to use other commands from further plugins to reduce the chance of someone figuring out that you are using **Bukkit**. An easy way to create a simple text response command is with a plugin like Bukkit [MyCommand](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/mycommand/).

- *Solve problem 7*:

Use Bukkit **MyCommand**, Bukkit **aliases**, and any other plugin you can find or create to override all commands for your plugins that users may use to test to see if that plugin exists. An easy way to do this in general is to simply respond ambiguously for all commands that do not exist as well as commands that the user has no privilege for. This is a sure way to prevent any user from figuring out traces of your plugins, and it does not require you to list out every single possible command for override.

Comment: [Click here](http://i.imgur.com/6dKghke.png) to see my reasoning for posting this answer and why PluginList is not sufficient.

Comment: You have a point: a player can check for what plugins are installed by trying to execute a command that correspond to those plugins, if the output message is "permission denied", then that plugin which has that command is installed. But when I posted the question all I wanted was just to hide the plugins so that my friends wouldn't be able to replicate my server gameplay and create their own server, I wanted my friends to play only on my server basically. So your point is kind of irrelevant while true.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use Bukkit Permissions and make the /plugins command an admin or op only command.

Answer (score 1):

You should add permissions so only the specific ranks you want them to do `/plugins`. The permission node is `bukkit.command.plugins`.

Or, you can add `-bukkit.command.plugins` to all groups that you *don't* want to have permission to `/plugins`. the `-` part removes the permission, as `/plugins` is available by default to every user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin for Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/%E2%9C%A6%E2%80%B9hidemyplugins%E2%80%BA%E2%9C%A6.37235/) which will hide your plugins. I'm not sure if you've solved this problem another way but I found this easier.